# How to transfer String from Fragment to Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to accomplish the transfer of a string value from a Fragment to an Activity below.  The result of the transfer says that the value is empty when transferred to the activity.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Fragment:

```
//put selected chapter title in memory

String selectedChapter = chapters[position];

SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
edt.putString("selectedChapter", selectedChapter);
edt.commit();

//launch activity
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChapterDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity:

```
   //retrieve selected chapter filename from previous view

    SharedPreferences pref = ChapterDetailActivity.this.getPreferences(0);
    String filename = pref.getString("selectedChapter", "empty");

    Log.e("File: ", filename);
```

Comment: When you use the activity's get preferences method, the file used to store preferences will be unique to that activity (= not visible elsewhere in your app). The answers already posted show two methods for creating preferences that are application wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to create a helper class for saving preferences. This will access them using a file name, instead of using the context. This means all your prefs are stored in one place, and you can create constants to hold the keys.

When passing a string literal like `"selectedChapter"`, the compiler has no way of checking if we mis-spelled the value. By creating a constant, the compiler will be able to check that the key exists.

```
public class PreferencesHelper {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "com.yourpackage.yourapp.prefs";

    public static final String KEY_CHAPTER = "chapter";

    public PreferencesHelper(Context context) {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    /**
     * Save the specified value to the shared preferences
     * 
     * @param key
     *            The key of the value you wish to load
     * @param value
     *            The value to store
     */
    public void save(String key, String value) {
        prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }


    /**
     * Load the specified value from the shared preferences
     * 
     * @param key
     *            The key of the value you wish to load
     * @param defValue
     *            The default value to be returned if no value is found
     */
    public int loadString(String key, String defValue) {
        return prefs.getString(key);
    }

}
```

Then, you activity can access it like so:

```
PreferencesHelper prefs= new PreferencesHelper(this);
```

And your fragments like so:

```
PreferencesHelper prefs = new PreferencesHelper(getActivity());
```

And to access the data:

```
// Save
prefs.save(PreferencesHelper.KEY_CHAPTER, chapter);

// Load
prefs.load(PreferencesHelper.KEY_CHAPTER, null)
```

Comment: The getString(key) requires another parameter for string values.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's for providing a default value, so you can pass `null` if you want, or just an empty string, whatever makes the most sense for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternative method to acquire your SharedPreferences object e.g. using the context

```
 SharedPreferences _preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
```

where you could get the context with getApplicationContext()

Then to read it's much as you have it:

```
 _preferences.getString(key,"");
```

and for write:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = _preferences.edit();
 editor.putString(key, val);
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: I tried this method and it kept crashing.  I set the key to a value such as "chapters" and the val to a string.  Then I couldn't figure out how to read the getString method so I put it as a ("chapters", "empty").  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have root on your device? It may be worth installing an app like root explorer and going into your app's data folder in /data/data/your package name/sharedprefs and checking the preferences XML file to see if your write was successful?